# How do I debug trigger recursion in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, debugging, recursion, triggers, plpgsql

How can I find out if a trigger I have is recursing or looping in PostgreSQL? **Is there an example of how to use it?**

I'm looking for an example of how to [add code to my current trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185354/2639) to check to see if the cause of a failure is recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`RAISE NOTICE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) on [`pg_trigger_depth();`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) Here is an example where we also use [`TG_NAME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int primary key);

CREATE FUNCTION bar()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
  BEGIN
    -- Debugging information
    RAISE NOTICE '[%] TRIGGER DEPTH %', TG_NAME, pg_trigger_depth();
    INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42);
    RETURN null;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER bar
  AFTER INSERT ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE bar();

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (41);
```

Running this yields

```
NOTICE:  [bar] TRIGGER DEPTH 1
NOTICE:  [bar] TRIGGER DEPTH 2
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(42) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42)"
PL/pgSQL function bar() line 5 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42)"
PL/pgSQL function bar() line 5 at SQL statement
```

While this will assist in debugging the situation [making a system dependent on this behavior is not a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163173/2639).